# UI automation clear textfield with the "Clear button"

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, xcode7, ios-ui-automation

Is there a way in UIAutomation to tap on the "Clear text" button of a textfield? Can you add an accessibility identifier to it, or does it already have one?

[image: textfield with clear text button]

At this moment I can only tap on the delete button of the keyboard or replace the textfield with an empty string. But I'd like to be able to tap on the clear text button that's being shown in my textfield.

Already found something in a comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821880/ui-test-deleting-text-in-text-field) issue:

textField.buttons["Clear text"].tap()

But this doesn't seem to work for me: "No matches found for this button"

Comment: Have you checked this? https://jojitsoriano.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/ios-ui-automation-tapping-the-clear-button-in-uitextfield/

Comment: I did, but this article is using UIAElement object, while I'm using the XCUIElement. Think the latter is the more recent version for UI testing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tap the text field first, so the button is visible:

```
let textField = app.textFields["Fanta"] // or however you're matching it
textField.tap()
textField.buttons["Clear text"].tap()
```

This works for me as a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it help you:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   textField.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: thanks, for your answer, but I don't want to change the behaviour of my application. I'm performing UI tests, so I want to mimic the exact behaviour of my customers.

Comment: Can you tapWithOptions({offset:{x:textfield.width - 25, y:textfield.height/2}})?