# Deleting text in text view during XC UI Test?

Tags: ios, xctest, ui-testing

I am trying to delete the previous value from text view,but I am unable to since the cursor is always at the beginning of text view.I am using

```
extension XCUIElement {
    /**
     Removes any current text in the field before typing in the new value
     - Parameter text: the text to enter into the field
     */
    func clearAndEnterText(text: String) -> Void {
        guard let stringValue = self.value as? String else {
            XCTFail("Tried to clear and enter text into a non string value")
            return
        }

        self.tap()

        let deleteString = stringValue.characters.map { _ in XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete }.joinWithSeparator("")

        self.typeText(deleteString)
        self.typeText(text)
    }
}
```

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32894080/2563133

Comment: Is there a clear button on your text field? (small grey x button on the right)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to rely on the keyboard and you are not making use of the clipboard, you can cut it:

```
extension XCUIApplication {
    func clearTextOnElement(_ element: XCUIElement) {
        element.doubleTap()
        menuItems["Select All"].tap()
        menuItems["Cut"].tap()
    }
}
```

Based on [Mr.ConstantChange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011041/8483739).

Comment: In my case I had to add an additional 
element.tap() 
before the doubleTap()

Comment: "Select all" is not visible on a real device.

Comment: I can't see "Select all" on my Simulator, it doesn't show up in the menu.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it is easy if you double tap on your textfiled and tap on the delete button from key board. Following code should work:

```
yourTextFieldElement.doubleTap()  
app.keys["delete"].tap()
```

Comment: thanks! i just needed to add this line between: menuItems["Select All"].tap()