# Regarding delete a string in swift

Tags: swift

I am unsure why but no matter what I try, this doesn't seem to delete the entire text in the text field even when I inspect it and see the same number of delete characters as there are characters to delete. It's seemingly random and deletes different amounts of characters each iteration.

---

```
extension XCUIElement {

    /**
     Removes any current text in the field before typing in the new value
     - Parameter text: the text to enter into the field
     */

    func clearAndEnterText(text: String) {
        guard let stringValue = self.value as? String else {
            XCTFail("Tried to clear and enter text into a non string value")
            return
        }


        let deleteString = String(repeating: XCUIKeyboardKey.delete.rawValue, count: stringValue.count)

        self.typeText(deleteString)
        self.typeText(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can easily just do.

`self.typeText.text = ""`

Comment: @Putte Thanks.But, it doesn't work. It appends "" to the existing string in the textfield.

Comment: So, why are you using the XCUIElement? What do you get from that? I just realized the typeText() is an inbuilt attribute, right?

Comment: I got this code from the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821880/ui-test-deleting-text-in-text-field

Comment: Sometimes it deletes all the characters as expected, but sometimes it leaves 2 or 3 chars undeleted.

Comment: Ok. So what's the idea of your app? What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Also, from the link you provided there is a comment in the answered post from Thomas Bak:

`"let deleteString = stringValue.characters.map { _ in "\u{8}" }.joinWithSeparator("")"`

Try that one.

Comment: Current version doesn't have "joinwithseparator".
My task is like I have to search a name in search field in a loop. Each and every time I have to clear the search field and enter the next name for a search

Comment: I've never used this extension before, so I can't really answer on that one sorry.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please suggest any swift developers?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /*!  * Sends a tap event to a central point computed for the element. 
> */
>
> - (void)tap;
>
> /*!  * Sends a double tap event to a central point computed for the element.  */
> - (void)doubleTap;
> ```

So if you send `tap` but text is longer than central point of control you will delete only left-part from the tapped point.

Try to use instead `doubleTap`, which as expected must select all text (exception, when selection will be disabled by some reason).

Comment: Sorry! I have edited the code part now. I am not using tap() functionality at all. My project is for appleTv and it doesn't have tap functionality. Without tap itself, I was able to clear the complete text sometimes.
Note : I am passing the same text for search all the time