# Xcode UI Test UIKeyInput typeText

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing, uikeyinput

During Xcode UI Testing, how do I `insertText` for a `UIView` that conforms to `UIKeyInput`?

I created a [`CodeInputView`](https://github.com/acani/CodeInputView) that conforms to `UIKeyInput`.

When I record myself manually entering a code, [Xcode writes `app.typeText("1234")`](https://github.com/acani/Chats-iPhone-Client/blob/8886431d55b7baf01fb409f5255fe7a0c2eec2a6/ChatsUITests/ChatsUITests.swift#L43).

But, when I try to play that back, I get the error [UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184837/ui-testing-failure-neither-element-nor-any-descendant-has-keyboard-focus-on-se). And, none of the solutions to that question has worked.

Comment: forums.developer.apple.com/message/29549#29549

Comment: btw, try to tap before typing. and check that  simulator settings: Hardware - keyboard - connect hardware keyboard (false)

Comment: I tried both of those things. I also tried Simulator > Reset Contents and Settings... Still not working.

Comment: I answered in the question you linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65335238/1837959

Answer (score 6):

I've found solution for UIKeyInput. Please, use:

```
app.keys["1"].tap()
app.keys["2"].tap()
app.keys["3"].tap()
app.keys["4"].tap()

// Instead of app.typeText("1234")
```

Comment: This works as intended, but it the test will fail if the simulator keyboard is down. It is also nice to add little timeout before tapping, as it has a tendency of failing with an invalid number of keystrokes every now and then...

Answer (score 2):

The `CodeInputView` needs focus before typing text will work. Access the input by either its placeholder text or set the accessibility label manually.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let codeTextField = app.textFields["Your code"]

codeTextField.tap()
app.typeText("1234")
```

> The above assumes the placeholder or accessibility label was set to "Your code".

Comment: I'll try that, but I don't think that will solve the issue as I don't need to click it during recording since I call `codeInputView.becomeForstResponder` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: First responder happens asynchronously so The framework might not have registered the change yet.

Comment: I tried it, but no luck. *Note: `CodeInputView` isn't a `UITextField`. It's a `UIView` that conforms to `UIKeyInput`.*