# Xcode UI Tests can't find views that are added programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I'm adding a child view to my view programmatically, and when I do I attach all accessibility params to it:

```
  [labelView setAccessibilityLabel:@"label"];
  [labelView setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
  [labelView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

But when I query the UI like this:

```
 let app = XCUIApplication()
 app.staticTexts["label"]
```

The test fails because it couldn't find the view.

How do I deal with this, how to make dynamically added views available for UI Testing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Just that a view has loaded, or are you trying to look for objects within the view?

Comment: Who is the parent of labelView?

Comment: I'm trying to read the label's content (.value).

@TomasCamin its a UIEditText but what difference does it make ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make sure that the container view of your label view (UIEditText?) doesn't have `isAccessibilityElement` set to YES. If it does it will hide the accessibility of its subviews (your label).

Check *Make the Contents of Custom Container Views Accessible* in the [Accessibility Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW10)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, while this is an understandable requirement for Accessibility design, its an obvious shortcoming in Xcode UI Testing.

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out myself, but in the end it kinda makes sense. Anyhow the docs are worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different solution because I caused myself a different problem that manifested in the same way, namely XCUITests couldn't find basic elements. My app uses a `UIWindow` with `UIWindow.windowLevel` set to `.normal + 2` to display a fullscreen loading spinner on top of the other windows. It turns out even when this window is not in the view hierarchy, or the accessibility hierarchy, or the responder chain, merely by its existence, it breaks the accessibility/view-hierarchy crawling system that UI tests use.

To verify this, I removed extra `UIWindow` instances entirely from the app. The fix ended up being simpler, just using `windowLevel = .alert` and not adding constants to UIKit's constants.