# Can not access the programatically added UIView in XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xctest, ui-testing

Below is my recorded XCTest

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let tablesQuery = app.tables
    tablesQuery.staticTexts["Video"].tap()
    tablesQuery.staticTexts["\tWindowed"].tap()
    app.buttons["Launch"].tap()
    app.buttons["Popout Video"].tap()
    app.children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 1).tap()
```

When I am trying to run the test the last part that is:

```
    app.children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 1).tap()
```

is not accessible. It does not throw any error but the last line of code is not executed.

I have tried solving the issue by referring to the following stackoverflow question : 
[Xcode UI Tests can't find views that are added programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776383/xcode-ui-tests-cant-find-views-that-are-added-programatically)

Also , I have referred to the following Apple Documentations: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW2

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview

But all these doesn't seem to solve the issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you look in the report log it will tell you details about why it is failing. It might even include a screenshot showing you the interface at that moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line in question is very brittle. It's possible that your app's views are not always available in the same order every time the app launches, depending on race conditions, so what was recorded in your recording session does not necessarily work for all launches of the app. You'll probably find that the code is actually running, but isn't tapping the element you expected.

To make your code less brittle, add an accessibility identifier to the UIView in your app code, and use the `otherElements` query to find the UIView.

```
// app code
let view: UIView!
view.accessibilityIdentifier = "myAccessibilityIdentifier"

// UI test code
app.otherElements["myAccessibilityIdentifier"].tap()
```

Comment: I tried this as well. It says:
 No matches found for "myAccessibilityIdentifier" Other

Comment: This worked. Actually, in my case the parent view to the UIView i wanted to access was having isAccessibilityElement  set to YES. So it was not working earlier.