# UIBarButtonItem's customView accessibility

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, xctest, xcuitest

I've created `UIBarButtonItem` with `customView` set to `BadgeButton` (a `UIButton` that has badge label added).

I am setting `accessibilityIdentifier = "properIDHere"` and `isAccessibilityElement = true`  for both: `aBadgeButton` and `aBadgeButton.badgeLabel`

When running UITests the badge button is visible and accessible by the ID, but the badgeLabel is not. Do you have ideas why?

```
final class BadgeButton: MyBaseButton {
   let badgeLabel = UILabel()

   override func addSubviews() {
    addSubview(badgeLabel)
   }

   override func setupConstraints() {
    badgeLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.width.height.equalTo(badgeSize)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview().offset(badgeXOffset)
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview().offset(badgeYOffset)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The runTime lable need a frame or constraint.

```
final class BadgeButton: UIButton {
        let badgeLabel = UILabel()
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            setupView()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            setupView()
        }

        func setupView() {
            self.addSubview(badgeLabel)
            badgeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
            //or you setup runTime Constraint
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, adding the badge as subview and layouting it seemed obvious to me. Badge is normally visible, but not through the XCTest accessibility inspector

Answer (score 0):

On the `BadgeButton` parent/custom view, try disabling accessibility. Leave it enabled for the UILabel.

After this, back in your `XCTestCase`, print out the XCUIApplication().debugDescription to see if you're now able to see the UILabel's accessibility information in the app's element hierarchy.

See this post as a possible duplicate:
[Xcode UI Tests can't find views that are added programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776383/xcode-ui-tests-cant-find-views-that-are-added-programatically)

[image]