# XCUITest - neither element nor descendant has keyboard focus

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am testing adding a comment to my app, on my other UI tests I have used the `typeText` function and everything works perfectly fine. I have also clicked to make Connect hardware keyboard' is off. The app terminates testing and shows the error UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus during the addComment method. Any ideas?

```
  func testAddComment() {
    let featuredPage = self.app.tabBars["Featured"]
    if featuredPage.exists {
        featuredPage.tap()
    }
    sleep(2)
    let featuredOffer = self.app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(1)
    if featuredOffer.exists {
        featuredOffer.tap()
    }
    sleep(2)
    let addComment = self.app.staticTexts["Add a comment"]
    if addComment.exists {
        addComment.tap()
        addComment.typeText("Test comment")
    }
    sleep(2)
    let postComment = self.app.buttons["Send"]
    if postComment.exists {
        postComment.tap()
    }
    sleep(2)
}
```

Comment: What's the type of your "Add a comment" component ? Is it an UITextField ?

Comment: @julienQuere yes its a textField , I have recent changed my addComment method.(see the edit, error still occuring)

Comment: Yes it is a UITextField

Comment: That's very strange. I tried your code and it works, but not with one simulator (6s plus). I keep digging :)

Comment: Hmm I am using the iphone 6 on the simulator, not sure if its an xcode error or not. appreciate your help!

Comment: In fact, there is serious issues with `XCUITest` and `typeText`. From my point of view: it do not work as it should be. So we have to try some crappy workarounds. You can take a look at this [bug report](https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/5100) or [this one](http://www.openradar.me/23899170).

Comment: It looks like you might not be focusing the UITextField when you tap on the staticText that's in the text field. In general, you should prefer interacting directly with the XCUIElement of the type you actually care about.

If you try to interact with the textfield instead of the staticText, what happens? And have you tried using the recorder (eheh, I know, but still)?

Comment: An answer to a similar question: [UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus on secureTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65335238/1837959)

Answer (score 8):

**Likely cause:**
An extremely common cause of this symptom is to have enabled a parent view of the field in question as an accessibility element. Ensure that none of the parents of the field are enabled as accessibility elements, and the problem is likely to be resolved.

**Explanation**
This error message can be particularly confusing when you can see that a previous step in the XCUITest has correctly activated a text field or similar as the first responder, the keyboard has appeared, and functionally the field has keyboard focus.

Essentially, the error message is slightly misleading as the tendency is to focus on the `keyboard focus` part and think that it is telling you that nothing has keyboard focus. Instead, what the message is telling you is that none of the *accessibility elements* that XCUITest can access have the keyboard focus. And so it can't direct text to the field in question.

Accessibility elements cannot have children that are also accessibility elements. Therefore, if you place a number of fields inside a view, but then mark that parent view as being an accessibility element, all of the field as its subviews become invisible to the accessibility frameworks. You can see and verify this is what is happening using the Accessibility Inspector app on the Mac alongside the simulator: the fields you are trying to target will not be selectable, and instead there will be a parent view that is.

Comment: This was an informative answer, but sadly didn't help me though I learned alot.

Answer (score 5):

I found the way around this best was to use `menuItem` and to paste what I wanted to the `textField` . This was a strange problem as both `textField` and `staticText` both didn't allow the test to run functionally. This is an issue I have reported to apple.

Here is my fix

```
    let addComment = self.app.staticTexts["Add a comment"]
    if addComment.exists {
        addComment.tap()
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "Test Comment"
        let commentTextField = self.app.staticTexts["Add a comment"]
        commentTextField.pressForDuration(1.1)
        sleep(1)
        app.menuItems.elementBoundByIndex(2).tap()
    }
```

Comment: I had a similar issue.  In fact, when I tried typeText, trying to type in the word "test", it would type "tttest".  In the console, I saw the message about checking for interrupting elements on the text field.  It would be nice to be able to force the action into the text field with some command.  The reason I state this is that on a real device, when I click into this same field, there is no problem with typing text in.  This problem only occurs when the xcuitests run.. Anyways, thanks for this, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `.typeText()` on an input element. Static texts are not input elements - they're just text. Your `addComment` constant is probably the placeholder text within your text field. Tapping on the placeholder text probably activates the text field and keyboard, but you cannot call `.typeText()` on the placeholder text as the text field is its parent, not its descendant.

You need to call `.typeText()` on your text field, which should have focus after you tap in it.

```
let addComment = self.app.textFields["addCommentIdentifier"]
if addComment.exists {
    addComment.tap()
    addComment.typeText("Test comment")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try solving this issue by using `.doubletap()` before you & enter the value in `.typeText(string)` it worked for me.

```
let addComment = self.app.staticTexts["Add a comment"]
    if addComment.exists {
        addComment.doubleTap()
        addComment.typeText("Test comment")
```

Answer (score -1):

Turn off `I/O -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard` in the Simulator menu.

When this option is on, the Simulator doesn't bring up the soft keyboard, so the OS (sometimes) thinks the text field is not focused. Most of my tests have no problem typing in text fields with this option on, but some fail, especially search bars.